# How to change button with plain backgroud color in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

In my project, I use bootstrap.

There are four Elems Cost,Custormer, question-sign and search button.

Here is my page code:

```
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li >
           <a href="#" >Cost</a>
        </li>
        <li >
           <a href="customerCenter.php" >Customer</a>
        </li>
        <li >
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" >
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          </button>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
           search
        </button>
    </form>
```

Now I want button of glyphicon-question-sign  has no backgroud-color while it is white with btn-default.

I have tried to use btn-inverse instead of btn-default, but unlucky it worked fail.

There is another question that  button of  glyphicon-question-sign is not at the same horizontal line with Cost and Customer.

I want the four Elems of Cost,Customer,glyphicon-question-sign,search are at the same horizontal line.

Who can help me?

Answer (score 1):

First you'll need to apply a class to the button in question.
Then you can apply `background: transparent` to that class to remove the white background.

As for getting things to be line, you simply need to give the elements `display: inline-block`.

Note that as the `<form>` has a fair bit of default styling, it will overlap the button. You'll probably want to offset this by giving it `float: right`. You also probably want to offset the inherent `margin-top` of `8px`, by reverting this back to `0`.

Finally, note that `navbar-nav` and `navbar-form` add in left/right margins of of `15px`. You'll probably want to revert these offsets back to `0`.

This can be seen in the following:

```css
.btn.transparent {
  background: transparent;
}

.nav, ul.nav > li, .navbar-form {
  display: inline-block;
}

form.navbar-form {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  float: right;
}

ul.navbar-nav {
  margin: 7.5px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Cost</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="customerCenter.php">Customer</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default transparent">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </button>
  </li>
</ul>
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
    search
  </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" aria-hidden="true" id="id-of-item">
```

and in css

```
#id-of-item{
 color:#ffa500;
 display:inline-block;
}
```

This will define the color of the glyphicon to be #ffa500 (orange) and will make it display inline as you require. You can treat glyphicons as text in this situation.